# Python 3: create in-memory Zipfile with in-memory Xml

Tags: python-3.x, io, zip

I am trying to create xml file with io.StringIO() and pack it into ZipFile, but the output is an empty zip file. Where is a mistake?

```
string_xml_buffer = io.StringIO()
string_xml_buffer.write('<MyContent>')
string_xml_buffer.write('</MyContent>')
bytes_zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
zf = ZipFile(bytes_zip_buffer, mode = 'w')
zf.writestr('filename.xml', string_xml_buffer.getvalue())

# Django response
response = HttpResponse(zf, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="f.zip"'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in missing `zf.close()`. With this row the code works great.